# When i click on page this error is raised Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)$']

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

blog.html

```
  {% block content %}

  <p>Blog's Title: {{ topic }}</p>

  <ul>
  {% for feed in blogs %}
    <li>
      <p>{{ feed.date_added|date:'M d,Y H:i' }}</p>
      <p>{{ feed.note|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>There are no Blogs Yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>


#Here is that Delete blog link.

  <p>Do you want to delete this Blog?</p>
  <a href="{% url 'mains:delete' deletej.id %}"> Delete This Blog</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

views.py ( This is the view for delete Blog )

```
def delete(request, blog_id):
    deletej = get_object_or_404(Blog,id=blog_id)
    deletej.delete()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('home')
```

urls.py

```
    path('delete/<int:blog_id>',views.delete,name='delete'),
```

When i click on Blog page then this Error ( Reverse for 'delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete/(?P<blog_id>[0-9]+)$'] ) is raised.

Please Help me in this. I will really appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give keyword arguments to your url in the templates.

```
<a href="{% url 'mains:delete' blog_id=deletej.id %}"> Delete This Blog</a>
```